# Different results on each system using file functions in C. Linux vs. Mac

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc

I currently am writing a file parsing program to parse some data. However, it needs to be run natively on a Mac OS machine. However, while the code will run fine on both Ubuntu 14.04 and Mac 10.10. The Mac machine will give some garbage data, sometimes. Using GCC on linux gives correct data all the time.

The source data is as follows,

```
[6/30/2015 11:20:09 PM] Stream Begin
[6/30/2015 11:20:09 PM] 00-00-FF-70-FC-A9-01-EC-FF-6C-FC-CC-01-FB-FF-70-FC-D4-01-FB
[6/30/2015 11:20:09 PM] 00-01-FF-74-FC-C8-02-0B-FF-68-FC-B5-01-FF-FF-70-FC-B5-02-03
[6/30/2015 11:20:09 PM] 00-02-FF-6C-FC-B9-02-03-FF-6C-FC-D0-02-17-FF-64-FC-C4-01-F4
[6/30/2015 11:20:10 PM] 00-03-FF-68-FC-C4-01-FF-FF-59-FC-C8-01-EC-FF-5C-FC-E0-02-1B
[6/30/2015 11:20:10 PM] 00-04-FF-5C-FC-DC-02-22-FF-5C-FC-D4-02-1E-FF-59-FC-C4-02-17
[6/30/2015 11:20:10 PM] 00-05-FF-60-FC-C4-02-13-FF-60-FC-C8-02-1B-FF-5C-FC-D0-02-1E
[6/30/2015 11:20:10 PM] 00-06-FF-68-FC-D4-02-1E-FF-68-FC-C0-02-22-FF-60-FC-C4-02-0F
[6/30/2015 11:20:10 PM] 00-07-FF-5C-FC-D0-02-03-FF-64-FC-B1-02-13-FF-59-FC-BD-01-FF
```

The desired output is as Follows. The first number is the sample number determined by line number. Each source line contains 3 output lines. Each number is represented by 4 hexadecimal characters.

```
1,-144,-855,492
2,-148,-820,507
3,-144,-812,507
4,-140,-824,523
5,-152,-843,511
6,-144,-843,515
7,-148,-839,515
8,-148,-816,535
9,-156,-828,500
10,-152,-828,511
11,-167,-824,492
12,-164,-800,539
13,-164,-804,546
14,-164,-812,542
15,-167,-828,535
16,-160,-828,531
17,-160,-824,539
18,-164,-816,542
19,-152,-812,542
20,-152,-832,546
21,-160,-828,527
22,-164,-816,515
23,-156,-847,531
```

However, on my mac, it's processing as follows.

```
1,-144,-855,492
2,-2368,-13114,507
3,-2293,-812,507
4,-140,-824,523
5,-2432,-13482,511
6,-2293,-843,515
7,-148,-839,515
8,-2368,-13050,535
9,-2485,-828,500
10,-152,-828,511
11,-2672,-13178,492
12,-2613,-800,539
13,-164,-804,546
14,-2624,-12986,542
15,-2661,-828,535
16,-160,-828,531
17,-2560,-13178,539
18,-2613,-816,542
19,-152,-812,542
20,-2432,-13306,546
21,-2549,-828,527
22,-164,-816,515
23,-2496,-13546,531
24,-2661,-835,511
```

I have tried compiling using clang, and gcc. Also tried using c99. Sometimes using xcode to compile I can get it to work, but if I move it from the source folder then it breaks again.

code source following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

static short readHexNumber(char * inputString);
static void processFile(FILE * inputFile);
//Main Function
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char c;
    char *input = argv[1];
    FILE *input_file, *output_file;
    char defaultOut[] = "output000.csv";
    char fileNumber = 0;
    char *fileNumberString;
    fileNumberString = defaultOut + 6;
    input_file = fopen(input, "r");
    output_file = fopen(defaultOut, "w");
    if (input_file == 0 || output_file == 0)
    {
        //fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure
        perror("Canot open file!!!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
    processFile(input_file);
    char currentLine[100];
    while (fgets(currentLine,100,input_file))
    {
        unsigned short lineNumber;
        short xNumber;
        short yNumber;
        short zNumber;

        char isNewFile = 0;
        char i;
        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            if(currentLine[i] == '\0'){
                ///found end of string
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i < 60){
            ///line is short, so we assume it's a new stream
            fileNumber+=1;
            char tempNumberString[4] = "000";
            sprintf(tempNumberString, "%03d",fileNumber);
            fileNumberString[0] = tempNumberString[0];
            fileNumberString[1] = tempNumberString[1];
            fileNumberString[2] = tempNumberString[2];
            fclose(output_file);
            output_file = fopen(defaultOut, "w");
            if(output_file == '\0'){
                //fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure
                perror("Canot open file!!!\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
            continue;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
            c = currentLine[i];
            if(c == 0){
                ///reached end of line
                break;
            }
            if(c == ']'){
                ///found end of header
                i+=2;
                break;
            }
        }

        lineNumber = (unsigned short)readHexNumber(currentLine + i);
        i += 6;
        char j;
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            xNumber = readHexNumber(currentLine + i + (18 * j));
            yNumber = readHexNumber(currentLine + i + (18 * j) + 6 );
            zNumber = readHexNumber(currentLine + i + (18 * j) + 12);
            fprintf(output_file,"%d,%d,%d,%d\n",3*lineNumber + j + 1, xNumber,yNumber,zNumber);
        }

    }
    }

    fclose(input_file);
    remove("interimFile");

    return 0;
}
static void processFile(FILE * inputFile){
    char * medianFile = "interimFile";
    FILE * interimFile;
    interimFile = fopen(medianFile,"w");
    char c;
    while((c = fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF){
        if(c == '\r'){
                ///if our character is a carriage return. check the next character
            if((c = fgetc(inputFile)) == '\n'){
                    ///if it's a new line, we just eat the carriage return character
                fputc(c,interimFile);
            }else{
                    ///if the next character isn't a newline character, we make it so
                fputc('\n',interimFile);
                fputc(c,interimFile);
            }
        }else{
                ///put the character into the next file
            fputc(c,interimFile);
        }
    }
    fclose(interimFile);
    fclose(inputFile);
    inputFile = fopen(medianFile, "r");
}
static short readHexNumber(char * inputString){
    char numberString[4] = "0000";

    numberString[0] = inputString[0]; //get MSB
    numberString[1] = inputString[1];//get next byte
    numberString[2] = inputString[3]; //get next byte
    numberString[3] = inputString[4];//get LSB

    short number = (short)strtol(numberString, NULL, 16);
    return number;
}
```

Comment: `char c;
    while((c = fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF){` c should be an int.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            if(currentLine[i] == '\0'){
                ///found end of string
                break;
            }` There is a strlen() function. You are free to use it.

Comment: `fileNumberString[0] = tempNumberString[0];
            fileNumberString[1] = tempNumberString[1];
            fileNumberString[2] = tempNumberString[2];` There is a function memcpy() you are free to use it. Also: sprintf() could be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 bytes allocated for `numberSring`. Who knows what character immediately follows the last one. There is a possibility that it looks like a digit. Make it `numberString[5]` and initialize `numberString[4] = 0`, to tell `strtol` where to stop.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this! Thank you